# Limit connection keep alive time in HTTP client 3.1

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I use the Apache HTTP client 3.1 with the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager to poll an API every couple second. Whenever a new version of the API is deployed, the DNS entries are changed to point to a new server. Since I use HTTP keep alive and the old server does not close the connection, I keep hitting the old server which leads to various problem. It does not help to use the IdleConnectionTimeoutThread since the connection is never idle for a longer time and I couldn't find an setting which lets me limit the time for which a connection is reused.

I don't want to disable keep alive because this would add too much overhead. My current idea is to set a new connection manager every minute and call the shutdown() method on the old connection manager. However, I am not convinced that this is the right approach. Is there any other way of solving this problem?

My restrictions are:

- I have to use HTTP keep alive
- I cannot control the API or the deployment of the service
- I cannot update to Apache HTTP client 4.x or another HTTP client

Comment: Why not just restart your client?

Comment: @Raedwald do you mean creating a new HTTP client? Restarting the whole application isn't an option.

Comment: Restarting the application must be an option.  How will you do maintenance of its computer otherwise. If they can, in effect,  restart the server, surely you can restart the client.

Comment: @Raedwald it isn't an option in this case because it leads to errors if I miss a deployment of the API service.